# Can I say to mail me referring to e-mail?

Tags: word-usage, email

Can I say someone to mail me when I'm referring to sending me to an e-mail?

I'm aware of other meaning of the word **mail**, but is it nowadays used in older meaning?

In many languages mail and e-mail are synonyms. Would an average native speaker younger than 40 also understand it that way?

Comment: Save yourself the hassle. Just say the extra syllable :P

Comment: I'm curious: How much [research](https://www.google.com/search?q="send+you+mail"&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t) did you do before asking this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *has* been used that way, most markedly by AOL back in the early '00s, but is really *isn't* used that way, at least in the US, or at least in the parts of the US where I have lived.

Some people may understand your meaning, others wouldn't. If you were to ask me to "mail" something to you, I would be confused, and take a few seconds to catch on. But if you said "email", I would immediately know what you mean.

So ultimately, it's a matter of clarity. Use "email". It isn't saving you any time to say "mail" instead, and you probably save time, since you don't need to wait for the other person to catch on.

Answer (score 5):

*Mail* is also used as verb to mean "send an email" ("Mail me when you are ready."), and as noun as synonym of *email*, such as in the following sentence: "You have got mail."

Comment: I've never heard the phrase "mail me ___" when referring to email (other than by AOL's mail service, which stopped that a long time ago). Have you?

Comment: Yes, I have. A friend of mine (American) told me "Mail me […]" to mean "Send me an email."

Answer (score 3):

You can ask someone to mail you, but should you?

> *Please mail me the file*

doesn't sound right to me. If we usually email each other and don't use postal mail, I would understand what you mean. But, I might be confused for a moment, or stop to think that it sounded awkward.

Even though *mail* as a noun sometimes means electronic mail, [mail as a verb](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=20655249) like in *mail me* usually means postal mail. There are not any examples in the COCA (Corpus of Contemporary American English - a set of recent spoken and written language samples) where *mail me* seems to mean email.

The use of *mail* might be changing or might be different for people whose English is not in the samples in COCA. But it is a safe choice to write *email* instead, as in:

> *Please email me the file*

If you want to choose a different word, [send](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=20655837) is common, as in *send me an email*, *send her a text*, or *send us the information*. Maybe because I hear and see *send* so much more than *mail*, *please send me the file* sounds normal to me. It would not confuse me (if we usually send emails and not postal mail).